# How to give an object alpha material?

Tags: transparency

I'm currently using a plane to conceal a few meshes in my scene (i'm using Cycles). This plane has a white emission surface, the same color as the background.

Is it possible to, instead of using a white material, give this plane an alpha material? Anything hidden behind this plane should thus not render.
It's worth mentioning that some objects are only partially concealed by the plane, thus I can not simply remove it from the scene.

For example:

In the image, I have a scene with two cubes, a plane and a monkey. The plane currently has an "alpha" shader/setting (this is the thing I want) assigned to it.

[image: Scene setup]

When rendered, the scene will look something like this:

[image: Final]

Anything behind the plane will disappear from the render, whilst anything in front of it will not be affected.

It's worth mentioning that some objects are only partially concealed by the plane, thus I can not simply remove it from the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an emission shader just add a "Holdout" shader and anything behind it will be left out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. If you are using Cycles then you could uncheck the camera box to hide any object you dont want to render.

[image]

If you want to show partial objects through your emission plane you would have to paint in a alpha mask in texture painting with a node set up like this.

[image]

You need to mix any shader with a transparent shader, and use what you paint as the mask.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I've updated the question to better explain it.